# Typescript - Get all implementations of interface

Tags: typescript

I'm searching for a way to get a list of all classes implementing a certain interface in Typescript.

In .Net for example, you can do this using reflection but i cant find any information about doing the same thing in Typescript.

Code example of what i want to do:

```
interface IControlPanel { }
class BasicControlPanel implements IControlPanel { }
class AdvancedControlPanel implements IControlPanel { }
window.onload = () =>
{
    var controlPanels = IControlPanel.GetImplementations();
    for (var x = 0; x < controlPanels.length; x++)
    {
        document.write(controlPanels[x] + ", "); //outputs: BasicControlPanel, AdvancedControlPanel,
    }
};
```

Even better would ofcourse be if the classes are easy to instantiate.

Comment: TypeScript has no runtime type information with which to determine this, not to mention that the structural type system implies that lots of things may implement `IControlPanel` without being declared as such.  You can maintain your own registry of appropriate class constructors, I guess.  Do you need help with that?

Comment: I know that i can keep my own registry and how to do it.
I never thought that there would be an expression that could be evaluated at runtime.
It would however be useful to get all implementations at compile time so that you simply don't have to keep this manual registry over the implementations.

Comment: What do you imagine `controlPanels` would be at runtime, then?

Comment: I imagine that an expression equivalent to IControlPanel.GetImplementations(); would get compiled to something like ["BasicControlPanel", "AdvancedControlPanel"].

Comment: No, that's a stated [non-goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) of TypeScript (see non-goal #5), sorry.

Comment: I guess that would fall under "emit different code based on the results of the type system" then.
My example could do entirely without runtime-metadata though.
Anyways, i guess that answers my question.
Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158105/discussion-between-doomdudemx-and-jcalz).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's a stated [non-goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) of TypeScript (see non-goal #5) to emit JavaScript that is dependent on the type system, so there will be nothing at runtime you can use automatically to do what you want.

You can, of course, use TypeScript to help you maintain a registry of types that can be used almost exactly how you want.  I'd suggest using [class decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), like so:

```
interface IControlPanel {
  // add some methods or something to distinguish from {}
  doAThing(): void;
}

// add a registry of the type you expect
namespace IControlPanel {
  type Constructor<T> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
    readonly prototype: T;
  }
  const implementations: Constructor<IControlPanel>[] = [];
  export function GetImplementations(): Constructor<IControlPanel>[] {
    return implementations;
  }
  export function register<T extends Constructor<IControlPanel>>(ctor: T) {
    implementations.push(ctor);
    return ctor;
  }
}
```

Now, instead of declaring that the class `implements IControlPanel`, you use `@IControlPanel.register`:

```
@IControlPanel.register
class BasicControlPanel {
  doAThing() { }
}

@IControlPanel.register
class AdvancedControlPanel {
  doAThing() { }
}
```

If you try to register a class that does not implement `IControlPanel`, you will get an error:

```
// error, doAThing is missing from BadControlPanel
@IControlPanel.register
class BadControlPanel {
  doNothing() { }
}
```

Now you can use the registry the way you want, mostly:

```
window.onload = () => {
  var controlPanels = IControlPanel.GetImplementations();
  for (var x = 0; x < controlPanels.length; x++) {
    document.write(controlPanels[x].name + ", ");
    const panel = new controlPanels[x]();
    panel.doAThing();
  }
};
```

I say "mostly" because I've stored constructors, not strings, since you wanted a way to instantiate them.  You can get the `name` property of the constructor for the string.  And you can instantiate the classes, assuming they all take the same constructor argument types.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/krhey5?file=index.ts)

Comment: That actually seems to be very elegant solution to my problem.
When you talked about maintaining a registry, i thought you meant manually adding entries to an array but this does more or less exactly what i want!
I'll try it out and then mark your answer.

Comment: I was too looking for a sort of javascript way of creating a plugin architecture in which I could reflect any code in scopr at runtime so that any types could be added at any time and the runtime reflection would pick this up. I had to do some research on decorators after coming across this post. This seems like a very elegant and scalable solution of which I plan to use only slightly modified for my needs

Comment: Do decorators always fire, even if class is not constructed? (Elegant solution, I like it!)

Comment: Yes, class decorators should fire once when the class is defined.  You can [check for yourself](https://typescript-play.js.org/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgJwIZSwCmiwC5ExUB3RfAOju0wHMBnU7MATwEpEBeAPkTtuiAN4AoRIgxhmcADaoa8uI3wAiACoALGM0R7EUbamkJmUTCCKZ1XANySzshUpVqbDpzLmLlqjR1cRApsfWNTH0trPFsvAF9xcQABNAwcWPEIeTD9ADE4ODEnACMGPkR1MoAPdUdE8SA).

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, I've decorated my classes and the register function never fires.

Comment: @HashSix I don't know what your problem might be; I've included a working stackblitz example above, so whatever is going on likely has to do with your specific environment. Please consider trying to produce a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're seeing; if you don't solve your own issue in the process of doing so, you could use such an example (or well-documented failed efforts to create one) as info to make a new SO question (since comment chains on 2-year-old answers don't usually get a lot of helpful eyes).  Good luck!

Comment: I need help! What to do if IControlPanel is parameterized? Like, `IControlPanel<T>`?

Comment: @richardsonwtr I guess it depends on what you need to do with it.  A comment section on a nearly 3-year-old question is probably not the best place to work this out, though.  I suggest you post your own question with a [mcve] that shows what your problem is and maybe what you tried to do to solve it.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, I've just separated into different files and stopped to work.

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/krhey5-z6rrle?file=index.ts

Comment: From the docs: NOTE! Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future releases. To enable experimental support for decorators, you must enable the `experimentalDecorators` compiler option either on the command line or in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Is there a static compile time version of this as well? I would like to make a string union like this: `type ImplementedNames = ``${Implementor['name']```

Comment: @jcalz is there any chance to add parameters to the register function ?